# Deep link opens browser instead of selected App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am trying to create an email confirmation using deep links in Kotlin

This is how the e-mail looks:

[image]

An example of link is **https://www.exampleee.com/?token=1239&tokenId=1234**

This is my manifest file:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".screens.login.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <data android:host="www.exampleee.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <data android:host="www.exampleee.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I click **Confirm Email** it just opens the browser without opening in the application.

This is what I get on the browser:

[image]

Do I need an website that is running? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can test with this snippet. You need add pathPattern in your intent-filter to mapper the url. You can also make test with app link assistant in your Android Studio.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPattern="/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: It does not work with this.

Comment: You need associate your host with app by assetlinks.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks

Comment: I dont have a host. The email is sent by the database (MongoDB).

Comment: Any idea why opens first the browser?

Comment: You can setting by open links in your device >> https://www.theverge.com/23036034/change-default-app-android-phone-browser-texting-assistant-how-to

In this link explains about app link >> https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: The problem is that web addresses are disabled by default. How I can solve this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over the "Confirm" link for the email, then you could try to create a unique link with a custom scheme/host. So instead of:

```
<data
   android:scheme="https"
    android:host="www.example.com"
     android:pathPattern="/*" />
```

you could try updating your link to:
[confirmemail://app.package.name/?token=1239&tokenId=1234](https://confirmemail://app.package.name/?token=1239&tokenId=1234)

Then do this:

```
<data
   android:scheme="confirmemail"
   android:host="app.package.name"
   android:pathPattern="/*" />
```